# spring synchronized transaction execution

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I have some Spring Serice marked as @Transactional.

```
@Service("SomeService")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public class SomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
       @Autowired
       SomeDao someDao;

       @Override
       public void methodA() {}

       @Override
       public void methodB() {}
}
```

I'm calling that service from @RestController class. Due specific business logic, I need that at the same moment there must not be more than one open transaction initiated by my service (I need sequential execution of all methods of service and all transactions opened by each method call).

I have an idea to mark that methods as synchronized, but I'm not sure that it's good for Spring inner logic. Maybe Spring already have any mechanism to execute transactions non-concurently, in a sequnce. Please help me to make right decision.

Comment: No, synchronized is all you have. Making calls sequential rather than concurrent is precisely what any serious framework tries to avoid, because it reduces the throughput , and reduces scalability. Also note that synchronized won't help if you have a cluster of servers.

Comment: Like @JB said, synchronized methods will not work across a cluster of servers.  You could use `isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE` with a long transaction timeout.  This will serialize your transactions at the database level and will work in a clustered environment.  However, note that using higher isolation levels such as `SERIALIZABLE` can severly hamper the throughput if the underlying database operation runs for a long time as requests will start to queue up.

Comment: To synchronized methods by using `isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE` with a datasource transaction manager, the applications in the cluster must share the same database instance.